# Radius of convergence greater than 1 if $f$ is analytic in $\left\{|z| < 1 \right\} \cup{} \left\{1 \right\}$ and $a_n \ge 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

We are doing Laurent series, singularity & Identity theorem at the moment, and I've been struggling to find a lead on this one. $f = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nz^n$ is analytic in $\left\{|z| < 1 \right\} \cup{} \left\{1 \right\}$ and $a_n \ge 0$, and I am supposed to prove that the convergence radius is greater than 1. I've tried to prove that since I can input 1 into the equation and $f(1)$ is a value, than the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges, but that only proves the radius is greater or equal to 1. Feel like I should probably use one of the things I mentioned above, but haven't really been able to find how. Would love even a hint! Thanks :)

Comment: My previous comment was in error; as a tiny hint you should think about what it means for your function to be analytic **at** a point, and then use the extra wiggle room provided to get a radius of convergence strictly larger than $1$.

Comment: And if the tiny hint is not enough and no one else can come in and give you a better hint, the entire answer is found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2771873/extending-convergence-radius-using-one-boundary-point).